# TikZ node positioning and keyvals

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

What's the best way to specify a node position on a path? The ways I found are not equivalent, which bothers me.

Why is `below right` different to `below, right` and `right, below`?
Why is `below right` different to `below=1pt, right=1pt` and `right=1pt, below=1pt`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to node [very near end, sloped, below right] {curve1} (20:6);
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to node [very near end, sloped, right, below] {curve2} (20:6);
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to node [very near end, sloped, below, right] {curve3} (20:6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to node [very near end, sloped, right=1pt, below=1pt] {curve1} (20:6);
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to node [very near end, sloped, below=1pt, right=1pt] {curve2} (20:6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Comment: If I recall correctly, separated `below` and `right` will overwrite each other.

Comment: I want to give values to both `below` and `right`, but doing so causes an error. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Use the `positioning` library: `\draw (0,0) to node [below right=5pt and 100pt] {n} (1,1);`. You are using deprecated syntax.

Comment: @cfr Is `below, right` the deprecated syntax you mention?

Comment: Sorry. I was confused when I wrote that. In any case, no, that's never been supported that I know of. (But I don't know the history.) It is really `below of=` etc. which is considered deprecated, I think. The recommended syntax is `below=<dim> of`. But that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything about positioning and anchors is explained in section [17.5 Positioning nodes](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=227) and it's worth to read it.

In any case I'll try to gave you some basic ideas about it.

The first and most important lesson is that any positioning command determines the node's anchor to be used. If you write `below`, what will be placed below this position will be the `north` anchor, and if you write `above right`, the anchor selected will be `south east`. (You can change this behaviour selecting a different anchor after the positioning option)

Second lesson, only the last positioning option survives. If you write `below, right` (with `,` between them) only `right` will be applied.

As an example:

```
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to 
node [pos=0, draw, sloped, above left] (al) {above left}
node [pos=0, draw, sloped, below right] {below right} 
node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, right, below] (rb) {right, below}
node [pos=1, draw, sloped, below, right] (br) {below, right}
(20:6);
```

will produce

[image]

Third lesson: when using new `positioning` library with explicit distance values like `above=2mm`, expressions like `above right=2mm` and `above right=2mm and 2mm` produce different results.

As an example, following code:

```
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to coordinate[pos=.5] (aux)
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, below right=3pt] {below right} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, above left=3pt] {above left} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, above right=3pt and 3pt] {above right} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, below left=3pt and 7pt] {below left} 
    (20:6);
```

generates

[image]

Of course, everything is much more better explained in previous link.

The complete code for previous examples is

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to 
node [pos=0, draw, sloped, above left] (al) {above left}
node [pos=0, draw, sloped, below right] {below right} 
node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, right, below] (rb) {right, below}
node [pos=1, draw, sloped, below, right] (br) {below, right}
(20:6);

\fill[red] (al.south east) circle(1pt);
\fill[red] (rb.north) circle(1pt);
\fill[red] (br.west) circle(1pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [out=40, in=150] to coordinate[pos=.5] (aux)
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, below right=3pt] {below right} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, above left=3pt] {above left} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, above right=3pt and 3pt] {above right} 
    node [pos=.5, draw, sloped, below left=3pt and 7pt] {below left} 
    (20:6);
\fill[red] (aux) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```